# Coalesce jsonArrayAgg to empty array in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq, postgresql-json

What is the equivalent for `coalesce` in the new jOOQ 3.14 SQL/JSON supporting version (in PostgreSQL)?

```
select coalesce(json_agg(t.*), '[]'::json)
from (select 'test' as mycol where 1 = 2) t;
```

The following unfortunately fails with the error "COALESCE types json and uuid[] cannot be matched".

```
coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(mycol), emptyArray<type>())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON.json()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html#json(java.lang.String)) or [`JSONB.jsonb()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSONB.html#jsonb(java.lang.String)), e.g.:

```java
coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(mycol), inline(json("[]")))
coalesce(jsonbArrayAgg(mycol), inline(jsonb("[]")))
```

But you can also use the [`jsonArray()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonArray(org.jooq.Field...)) or [`jsonbArray()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonbArray(org.jooq.Field...)) constructors:

```java
coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(mycol), jsonArray())
coalesce(jsonbArrayAgg(mycol), jsonbArray())
```